# Postgres schema for Users & Approving Users for a Dating style app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Users see profiles of other Users and mark `approve` or `reject`, ala Tinder or similar dating apps.

I am building a Rails server with ActiveRecord & PostgreSQL on the backend.

I am considering having a `User` model, then an `Approval` model which has `user_id` and `approved_id`.

Approval:

```
  create_table "approvals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "approved_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "user1_approval"
    t.datetime "user2_approval"
    t.datetime "denied_at"
  end


class User

  has_many :approvals
  has_many :approved, through: :approvals
  has_many :inverse_users, class_name: "Approval", foreign_key: "approved_id"
  has_many :inverse_approvals, through: :inverse_users, source: :user

class Approval

    def self.user_approval(user1, user2)
        sorted = [user1, user2].sort_by { |u| u.name}
        Approval.find_or_create_by(user: sorted[0], approved: sorted[1])
    end
```

This has the advantage of limiting the number of `Approval` objects - there would be only 1 for each pair of `User`s. However, I am uncertain how to efficiently query with this schema.

When looking up the `approve` or `reject` action, for example, I have to manually check if the submitting `user_id` matches `user_id` or `approved_id` to set `user1_approval` or `user2_approval` appropriately.

I am considering looking up `User`s by a simple filter (age range within 10 years)

so that in `User` I have:

```
def self.eligible(user) 
    users = User.where('age >= ? AND age <= ? AND id != ?', user.lowest_eligible_age,user.maximum_eligible_age, user.id).limit(20)

    approvals = []
    users.each do |u|
      approvals.push(Approval.user_approval(user, u ))
    end

    approvals.reject! { |a| a.denied_at}

    approvals

  end
```

Which works great for getting a shortlist of eligible Users. It also has the advantage of allowing an api of `/approvals/:id/approve` & `/approvals/:id/reject`.

I'm wondering if it makes more sense to use an API like `/users/:id/approve` and then have that action generate the `Approval` accordingly. Each `Approval` object would have a `user_id` and also a `related_approval_id` so it could link to a mutual `Approval` (where the target User is the same as the linked approval's `user_id`).

```
  create_table "approvals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "approved_id"
    t.integer  "related_approval_id"
```

Doing that makes for a lot more rows in the database.

I hope this makes sense. I'm looking for a good architecture solution to Users approving & rejecting each other that allows me to make good queries like only showing `User`s which the `current_user` has not approved and which have not rejected current_user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the user can either be "approved" or "denied" ala Tinder, it makes more sense to call this model a Decision.  Here's how I see this playing out.

### User Model

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "id"
  t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
  t.integer  "age"
  ...etc...
end
```

The user model represents any user of the app who would make a decision about another user or another user would make a decision about.

### Decision Model

```
create_table "decision", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "id"
  t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
  t.integer  "decision_maker_id"
  t.integer  "decision_receiver_id"
  t.boolean  "approved"  
  t.boolean  "active"
  ...etc...
end
```

A decision represents any interaction between users.  A swipe right on a user is one decision.  A responding swipe right from the opposite user is another decision.  This is not represented as one whole object rather as two separate "decision" interactions.

Let me explain what the fields in Decision mean:

- decision_maker_id - the id of the user who does the swiping
- decision_receiver_id - the id of the user who is receiving the swip
- approved - a boolean which would be true if the swipe was right and false if the swipe was left
- active - a boolean which determines whether this decision has had a reply decision yet

In the **Decision model**, you would need a before_save callback that would check if the decision that is being saved has already has a counterpart reply decision.  If it does then you would want to make the decision no longer active so that it doesn't show up on the feed anymore.  Then, you can notify the users they agreed/disagreed or whatever you wish to do at that point in your app.

```
before_save: check_for_existing_reply

def check_for_existing_reply
  # if there is a decision object with this decision_maker_id and this 
  # decision_receiver_id but in opposite fields then you know there is a reply 
  # and you can take some action here
end
```

In the **User model**, you can write methods that find all of the active approvals/rejections that exist.

```
scope :decisions, -> (id, approval_type) { where('decision_receiver_id = ? AND approved = ? AND active = true', approval_type) }
```

By calling that scope with `User.decisions(user_id, true)` you could get all of the approvals for a user.  By calling that scope with `user.decisions(user_id, false)` you could get all of the rejections for a user.

You could also break this up into two separate scope, one for approvals and one for rejections.

```
scope :approvals, -> (id) { where('decision_receiver_id = ? AND approved = ? AND active = true', true) } 
scope :rejections, -> (id) { where('decision_receiver_id = ? AND approved = ? AND active = true', false) }
```

Finally, you could make this a method that is called on an instance of User so you don't have to pass the id parameter in.

```
# where decision = true would mean approvals and decision = false would mean rejections  
def get_decisions(decision)  
   return User.where('decision_receiver_id = self.id AND approved = decision AND active = true') }  
end
```

And you could call this on an instance of User like `user.get_decisions(true)`.

Comment: @Mike great advice but I don't really get the reason why the `approvals`/`rejections` scopes should be in the `User` model given that at the scope level the model isn't aware of whichever `Decision`s are associated to that `User`

Moreover, the User model doesn't have the `decision_receiver_id` so it's very probable that one will get an ORM error such as `ERROR:  column "seller_id" does not exist at character 38` when trying to call this scope.